# For loop inside which it's possible to modify the index

Tags: r, for-loop

I'd like to know how can I implement a for loop like this in R (I wrote the code for C):

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
    print the index i
    i = desiredNumber
}
```

It seems that this is not possible in R because, when I modify the index inside a for loop, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `while` loop

```
flag <- TRUE
 i <- 1
 while(flag) {
   print(i)
   i <- i + 1
   if(i > 10) {
    flag <- FALSE
   } 
 }
```

Output:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am missing something but in R `for` loop you don't need to increment `i` explicitly.

```
n <- 10
for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  print(i)
}

#[1] 1
#[1] 2
#[1] 3
#[1] 4
#[1] 5
#[1] 6
#[1] 7
#[1] 8
#[1] 9
#[1] 10
```

`seq_len(n)` creates a sequence from 1 to `n`.

Comment: Hello @RonakShah I need a solution like the akrun's one to implement a particular algorithm. Thank you for your answer